# Class and attributes/members in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab

I'm learning python.

project is a Project object that you need to create before trying to access its members attributes.how to access member attributes.

class Project(object):

Comment: Um, I'm really not sure what you're asking. Do you mean the `.` operator?

Comment: This question is not clear at all. Please revise and show what work you've already done toward solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know about classes in Python3 as well as the information provided below was taken from & should be [found here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

And here is an example code that I think might be helpful (file attached):

```
class Project:
# Class objects support two kinds of operations:
## Attribute references (skip to this part) and
## Instantiation (probably not what you asked about but is essential).

# Instantiation ("calling" a class object) creates an empty object with instances usually customized to a specific initial state.
## A special widely used method (called a class constructor in other programming languages such as C++) is:
### __init__()
## and here's an example of it:
def __init__(self):
    self.data = []
# When a class defines an __init__() method,
# class instantiation automatically invokes __init__() for the newly-created class instance.
# So in this example, a new, initialized instance can be obtained by:
# x = Project()
# Read more about __init__() in "9.3.3. Instance Objects" in the link provided.


#Attribute references such as:
object1 = "First object in Project"
object2 = 3.14666420

def functionOfProject(self):
    return "Project's function was accessed!"
#------- testing the code above in a main function ------#
def main():
# These will NOT work because no Project object was created:
## print(Project.object1)
## print(Project.object2)

# We can create a Project object named "project1" and invoke it's attributes as in the following:
project1 = Project()

print(project1.object1)
print(project1.object2)
project1.functionOfProject

main()
```

Hope this helps.